# Persisted permissions for CRM using CASL

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, crm, casl

I'm currently exploring CASL for managing persisted permissions in my MERN stack CRM application, specifically for granting access to the entire hierarchy of employees under a manager. Has anyone successfully implemented CASL for this purpose?
I am storing a managerId field in user schema that links the employee to his manager. I also want the permission to be stored jn database and described in the official docs linked below. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

https://casl.js.org/v6/en/cookbook/roles-with-static-permissions

I am able to give access and filter out documents that are owned by a direct reportee to a manager by specifying the condition as {
id: 1,
name: 'manager',
permissions: JSON.stringify([
{ action: 'manage', subject: 'Order', conditions: { ”owner.managerId: '${user.id}' } },
])
}

I am not able to figure out how yo give access to all employees that don’t directly report to a particular manager.